# Magento frontend and backend page looks different

Tags: magento, firebug, firephp

I am a newb in magento and recently started looking at it to create a store for my client.
I am not sure but i tried installing firephp extension and soon after that I’m having my screen looks like the screenshot. ** please check the link provided!

Do I have to make any installations to get everything working as normal or what am I suppose to do to go to the normal screen. I have also changed the inline translation option to NO if thats what it requires.
Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers I have also posted this question on the magento forum

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/193499/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you turned on some sort of template building helper that shows what templates generate which parts of the page.

Some quick googling found [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/behind-the-scenes-template-path-hints/), which appears to be the one. Look for "Template Path Hints" in the settings and [turn it off](http://www.topinternetguides.com/2008/05/26/magento-tutorial-turning-on-template-path-hints/).

Comment: Hi Thanks I got to that level but even after disabling that feature I cant get rid of the hints.. Tried changing it from the xml file too..by this "http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/5924/" but still cant figure out...magento is too slow I suppose...